# How can I run Visual Studio for mac as administrator?

Tags: macos

I use Visual Studio for Mac Community 8.4.1 (build 4) on my iMac.
How can I run Visual Studio as administrator? How can I find out if I am in administrator mode?

I need to have rights to read a file that is located in desktop directory:

```
  string assetPath = "/Users/myname/Desktop/Level2.txt";
  try
  {
      File.SetAttributes("/Users/myname/Desktop/Level2.txt", FileAttributes.Normal);
      byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(assetPath);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Exception :" + e.ToString());
  }
```

My code is not working. I get this error message:

```
"Access to the path \"/Users/myname/Desktop/Level2.txt\" is denied."
```

Why is the access to the path denied? Will it help if run Visual Studio as administrator?

Comment: What version of macOS?  Does it work in a non-restricted location? Not Desktop or Downloads - try something like  `/Users/myname/TESTFOLDER/Level2.txt` rather than `/Users/myname/Desktop/Level2.txt`

Comment: It’s very important that you let us know which version of macOS you’re running - I suspect Catalina. “Running as Administrator” is not the same thing as it is on windows. There, you get elevated privileges, on Unix, you run it as root. In short, it’s not a solution to your problem.

Comment: I have macOS Catalina. Thanx, it works with: /Users/myname/TESTFOLDER/Level2.txt